# Create Travis NAT IPs as AWS VPC Security Group IP List

Tags: amazon-web-services, travis-ci

I'd like to create a Security Group rule in AWS to allow incoming SSH connections from Travis (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ip-addresses/) to be able to control deployment.
AWS has a limit on the individual rules in the Security Group, adding IPs one by one is not an option due to that.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Fetch and parse https://dnsjson.com/nat.travisci.net/A.json
# for all the IP addresses that Travis CI uses for NAT.
TRAVIS_NAT_IPS=$(wget -qO- https://dnsjson.com/nat.travisci.net/A.json | jq -r '.results.records[]')
readarray -t IP_ADDRESSES <<< "$TRAVIS_NAT_IPS"
ENTRIES=""
for IP in "${IP_ADDRESSES[@]}"
do
    ENTRIES="$ENTRIES""Cidr=$IP/32,Description=Travis "
done

aws ec2 create-managed-prefix-list \
    --address-family IPv4 \
    --max-entries 100 \
    --entries="${ENTRIES##*( )}" \
    --prefix-list-name travis-nat-ips
```

The error it throws:

```
Error parsing parameter '--entries': Second instance of key "Description" encountered for input:
This is often because there is a preceding "," instead of a space.
```

But I could not locate the issue, as the syntax matches the example in AWS doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-managed-prefix-list.html#examples

Any pointers how should we correct the above shell script or how should we do it in a different way?
Opening port 22 to the public (0.0.0.0) permanently is not an option for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working version of the shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Fetch and parse https://dnsjson.com/nat.travisci.net/A.json
# for all the IP addresses that Travis CI uses for NAT.
TRAVIS_NAT_IPS=$(wget -qO- https://dnsjson.com/nat.travisci.net/A.json | jq -r '.results.records[]')
readarray -t IP_ADDRESSES <<< "$TRAVIS_NAT_IPS"
ENTRIES=""
for IP in "${IP_ADDRESSES[@]}"
do
    ENTRIES="$ENTRIES""Cidr=$IP/32,Description=Travis "
done

aws ec2 create-managed-prefix-list \
    --address-family IPv4 \
    --max-entries 100 \
    --entries ${ENTRIES##*( )} \
    --prefix-list-name travis-nat-ips
```